# How can I get the last 10 records added to a datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am storing entities like such

```
Entity entity = new Entity("Feedback");
entity.setProperty("text", searchText);
datastore.put(entity).getId();
```

How can I query the datastore for the last 10 feedback entries stored?

What I have now returns everything. with a limit it returns the first 10. How can I return the last ten?

```
Query query = new Query("FeedBack");
List<Entity> feeds = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Comment: When you insert a new entity, you can set a date property with the current timestamp. Then you can order with this property, DESC, and get the first 10 entries

Comment: A datetimestamp is pretty much the only way, but it may not be 100% accurate due to eventual consistency.

Answer (score 2):

When you add your entities to the Datastore, you have no guarantee that they will be returned in any particular order. If you want entities to be sorted according to some criteria, you must use an indexed property and set a sort order on this property in your query.

In your case, you need to add a property "Date" and add a timestamp to each entity before saving it:

```
entity.setProperty("date", new Date().getTime());
```

Now you can add a sort order to your query - ascending or descending - and set a limit to 10.